# android TransalteAnimation on Bitmap

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to draw movable bitmap in canvas, I need to move it by matrix from TransalteAnimation

I have this code:

```
float[] values = new float[9];  
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(-100,100, 0, 0);
slide.setDuration(100);
slide.setRepeatCount(TranslateAnimation.INFINITE);
slide.setRepeatMode(TranslateAnimation.REVERSE);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
Transformation transform = new Transformation();
slide.start();
slide.getTransformation(AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis(), transform);
            transform.getMatrix().getValues(values);
```

but it never changed, values are always: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

where I make mistake?

**its works any other type of animation: RotateAnimation, AlphaAnimation and etc.. its not work exactly on Translate Animation**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer, its need to to call  `slide.initialize(0, 0, 0, 0);`